# Parsing String and Int in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, int

Im using java and I have a String that I would like to parse which contains the following

```
Logging v0.12.4
```

and would like to split it into a String containing

```
Logging
```

and an integer array containing

```
0.12.4
```

where

```
array[i][0] = 0
```

and

```
array[i][1] = 12
```

and so on. I have been stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: I don't seen any Java code in your question. What have you tried?

Comment: Please show us the code you wrote so far.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Will there always be 2 `.`?

Comment: @Pshemo I think your edit removed too much of the question.

Comment: @Tichodroma You may be right. I didn't pay much attention to fact that OP is using 2D array (which is kind of confusing here).

Comment: You can't achieve this (for a 2D array) in 1 `split()` call. You should use 2 `split()` calls  as shown by *Pshemo*

Comment: @OP "*where `array[i][0] = 0`*" what is `i` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- split your string on space to get `Logging` and `v0.12.4`
- remove (substring) `v` from `v0.12.4`
- split `0.12.4` on dot (use `split("\\.")` since dot is special in regex)
- you can also parse each `"0"` `"12"` `"4"` to integer (`Integer.parseInt` can be helpful).

Comment: Best way to answer, if the OP hasnt shared his code +1

Comment: split by `\\s.` :) . That will *remove* the *substring step*

Comment: @TheLostMind Neat but it may be too much for OP right now. I would rather focus on general approach then optimization. Anyway `"\\sv"` would be probably clearer :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I know i was a bit of a Knob question but what i was doing wasn't working for me but its working now, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex or just normal String splitting

```
String myString = "Logging v0.12.4";
String[] parts = myString.split(" v");
// now parts[0] will be "Logging" and
// parts[1] will be "0.12.4";
```

Then do the same for the version part:

```
String[] versionParts = parts[1].split("\\.");
// versionParts[0] will be "0"
// versionParts[1] will be "12"
// versionParts[2] will be "4"
```

You can "convert" these to integers by using [Integer.parseInt(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: OP wants version parts to be tokenized also

Comment: ... and parsed into integers :)

Comment: Given the fact that there is no code provided I find it perfectly OK to provide also a pseudo-solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go buddy, because I'm feeling generous today:

```
String string = "Logging v0.12.4";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.+?)\\s+v(.*)").matcher(string);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    String name = matcher.group(1);
    int[] versions = Arrays.stream(matcher.group(2).split("\\.")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
}
```